# Python clustering and labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

i'm currently experimenting with scikit and the DBSCAN algorithm. And i'm wondering how to combine the data with the labels to write them into a new file. I'd also like to understand how the labels array is used to filter the examples.

Please correct me anytime i say something wrong because i'd like to understand the whole process better.

For example my data looks like this:

```
city    x    y
A       1    1
B       1    1
C       5    5
D       8    8
```

So if i understand it correctly i first need to split the data i'd like to cluster. If i use the data like above it will consider the *city* column aswell (or even fail).

So my next array would look like this:

```
x    y
1    1
1    1
5    5
8    8
```

Now i'll use the DBSCAN on my Array and it will create a cluster model. The clusterlabels are now stored in the array *foo.labels_*.

As far as i know i can filter the data with those labels to get the items within the clusters. Let's assume my data is in the dataframe *cities*:

```
cluster0 = cities[foo.labels_ == 0]
```

What i don't understand is how this works. I somehow don't get what exactly happens here. I know that the labels are in an array where the column is a number and the value of the column is the cluster. So how do i get the correct index of my cities?

So after the clustering i'd like to export my data back into a CSV file with the following format:

```
city    x     y     cluster
A       1     1     0
B       1     1     0
C       5     5     1
D       8     8     2
```

My guess is to use to original dataframe and add another column like this:

```
cities = cities.assign(cluster=p.Series(labels_))
```

But i'm absolutely unsure if that's the correct way to achieve what i want to do.

I'd really appreciate some opinions and explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the algorithm should not change the order of the lists you could just add the clusters list

```
 cities["cluster"] = cluster
```

If you are really paranoid you can add your input parameters a second time to the dataframe in the same way and compare the diff in values (should be 0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So it's basically two lists in the same order which get joined again. I thought there is a littile bit more _intelligence_ behind it. 
If i understand it correctly than my idea with `cluster0 = cities[foo.labels_ == 0]` would return a wrong result or am i wrong?

Comment: well not a wrong result but only the subset where this is the case. if this happens the order is broken and you cannot proceed easily. To my knowledge you cannot assign a list to a dataframe with different length.